# Can I use a function as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, parameters

I have an AJAX function inside a javascript file and I want it to be abstract and not to use any global variables.

The AJAX inserts an event into a database:

```
function insertCalendarEvents(calendar_group, event_name, event_datestart, event_datestop, event_timestart, event_timestop, event_info, onFinish) {
    var request;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            if(request.responseText.substr(0, 6) == "error ")
                alert(errorName[request.responseText.substr(6)]);
            else {
                var event_id = request.responseText;
                //call onFinish function with parameter event_id which database assigned it
            }
        }
    }

    request.open("GET", "php/calendar.php?action=insertCalendarEvents&calendar_group=" + calendar_group + "&event_name=" + event_name + "&event_datestart=" + event_datestart + "&event_datestop=" + event_datestop + "&event_timestart=" + event_timestart + "&event_timestop=" + event_timestop + "&event_info=" + event_info, true);
    request.send();
}
```

The function is asynchronous so what I want to do is, at the moment it finished inserting the data into the database, I want it to execute a function which I will give it as a parameter.

If there is a better idea on how to accomplish this, I would be really happy to hear it :)

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: Did you try `onFinish(event_id)`?

Comment: ow i just tryed it and it seems to work :)
where i called the function i used (function() { //stuff }); inside the parameter zone

Comment: you might want to consider using a JavaScript library (such as jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to help you with Ajax calls

Comment: the problem i hate on using ajax with jquery is that i need to write the $(document).ready(function() {}); before the function .. while on simple javascript with ajax i can simply implement a function which works even if i dont have jquery plugin, and works without writing extra code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are just objects you can pass. The only extra thing is that you can call them using `()` (additionally with arguments, of course).

You can pass them around just fine; all information such as scoping will be preserved. So, this should work:

```
onFinish(event_id);
```

Basically, a more trivial example would be this:

```
function func() {
  alert("func is being run");
}


func();  // works


function callFunction(f) {
  f();
}

callFunction(func);  // pass func; works


callFunction(function() {             // pass a function on the fly; works
  alert("function passed directly");  // (nothing special in fact)
});
```

Comment: yes i have used this idea to code my way out of this problem and it works exactly how i wanted it to work, i understand this isnt such a complex problem but it was for me since i just started to work in jquery and javascript in general only like 1 month :) thank you very much, Daniel.